# Politically charged answer incorrectly deleted by mod

Tags: discussion

In my opinion this answer was incorrectly deleted: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46670/4555

The main objectional part of it was the last line, which was easily edited out.  The rest of the post, although a bit highstrung, was a legitimate answer capable of being judged via votes rather than deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deletion almost certainly was because of the username, not the content of the answer. There was a user's flag pointing out that while the answer in and of itself *might* be ok, the username certainly is not.

As the comment by Dave pointed out (he did not put up the flag, btw), this was a rather gross violation of the be nice policy, so the deletion was justified by this, not the content.

Edit: As @virmaior pointed out in comments, we can change the username. As this was the main concern, I undeleted the answer and deleted comments merely referring to the username after setting the username to the system default.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: That was indeed my reason.

Comment: I flagged it because of the name. I believe there's actually an interface somewhere where mods can *change* someone's username itself.

Comment: @virmaior: Yep, we can actually edit user profiles as if we were the user to edit inappropriate content out. I changed the username to default and undeleted the answer.